# Error while creating Dialog Fragment Inside Sub Menu Item in android activity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, submenu, android-dialogfragment

I have created a dialog fragment. I need to get this dialog come to my current activity as soon as I press the submenu item. So I have created and declared AlertDialog.Builder builde; inside the starting of my activity.

```
public class Placed_Product_Details extends Activity {
String usrnme,name,proid;
AlertDialog.Builder builde;
```

Its code is below.

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    builde = new AlertDialog.Builder(Placed_Product_Details.this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = Placed_Product_Details.this.getLayoutInflater();
      // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builde.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.updateproductname, null))
    // Add action buttons
           .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // sign in the user ...
               }
           });

    return builde.create();

}
```

This is the portion of submenu code.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.delete:
    {

        //here i have the code for deleting from the database

        break;
    }
    case R.id.updateproductname:
    {

                //here I have created a dialog and called it here. The code 
                 //of the dialog is posted above
        AlertDialog ab=builde.create();
        ab.show();
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

This is the layout of my created dialog updateproductname.xml in the res/layout/ folder of my project.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Update Product Name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/productnameedittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:hint="Enter new product name here"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/productnamebutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Change Product Name" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When I click on the sub menu my application force closes suddenly. I don't know why? I will show the logcat which shows the error. Is this because I created the dialog fragment wrongly. Can someone show me where the error is in my application.

EDIT: Here is the complete log of my error..

```
02-17 10:50:23.267: D/AndroidRuntime(687): Shutting down VM
02-17 10:50:23.318: W/dalvikvm(687): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
 02-17 10:50:23.416: E/AndroidRuntime(687): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 10:50:23.416: E/AndroidRuntime(687): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-17 10:50:23.416: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at com.example.onlineauction.Placed_Product_Details.onOptionsItemSelected(Placed_Product_Details.java:188)
02-17 10:50:23.416: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2205)
02-17 10:50:23.416: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:748)
02-17 10:50:23.416: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:143)
02-17 10:50:23.416: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
02-17 10:50:23.416: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:137)
02-17 10:50:23.416: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:873)
02-17 10:50:23.416: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
02-17 10:50:23.416: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
02-17 10:50:23.416: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
02-17 10:50:23.416: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-17 10:50:23.416: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-17 10:50:23.416: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-17 10:50:23.416: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-17 10:50:23.416: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 10:50:23.416: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-17 10:50:23.416: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-17 10:50:23.416: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-17 10:50:23.416: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-17 10:50:27.746: I/Process(687): Sending signal. PID: 687 SIG: 9
```

2nd EDIT: Here is the second logcat showing the errors.

```
02-17 12:07:11.577: E/AndroidRuntime(769): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 12:07:11.577: E/AndroidRuntime(769): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-17 12:07:11.577: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at com.example.onlineauction.Placed_Product_Details$1.onClick(Placed_Product_Details.java:212)
02-17 12:07:11.577: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:159)
02-17 12:07:11.577: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-17 12:07:11.577: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-17 12:07:11.577: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-17 12:07:11.577: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 12:07:11.577: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-17 12:07:11.577: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-17 12:07:11.577: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-17 12:07:11.577: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-17 12:07:15.667: I/Process(769): Sending signal. PID: 769 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Could you just post the whole log instead of a part of it.

Comment: @user1728071. Whole Log posted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first the variable `builder` is not initialized as `onCreateDialog()` is not called any where...

You may be thinking that you are overriding `onCreateDialog()` method of `Activity` but actually not.

see the definition of `onCreateDialog()` in `Activity`

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int);
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int,Bundle);
```

FYI... these two methods are deprecated.

but you wrote

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle);
```

which does not override any method of `Activity`...(use `Override` annotation to know you are actually overriding or not)

You can remove the `Bundle` parameter from `onCreateDialog()` method as you are not using it.

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    builde = new AlertDialog.Builder(Placed_Product_Details.this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = Placed_Product_Details.this
            .getLayoutInflater();
    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builde.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.updateproductname, null))
    // Add action buttons
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // sign in the user ...
                }
            });

    return builde.create();
}
```

and call this method when appropriate `MenuItem` is clicked...

```
case R.id.updateproductname:{

    //here I have created a dialog and called it here. The code 
    //of the dialog is posted above
    onCreateDialog().show();
    break;
}
```

Comment: @ Gopal Rao. Please forgive me if I'm saying a blunder. Can you please explain to me where should I call the onCreateDialog() so that the variable builde will be initialized.

Comment: @ Gopal Rao.
When I tried to access a value from the edittext productnameedittext, my app force closes. Why is this? I have written the following piece of code in my 

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // sign in the user ...
EditText productname=(EditText) findViewById (R.id.productnameedittext);String newproname=productname.getText().toString();
                 //Toast.makeText(Placed_Product_Details.this, newproname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

Comment: @user1547124 normally when you say your app force closes, consider posting the logcat error too... (We are not magicians here to find error)

Comment: @user1547124 so your `productname` EditText is `null`. i.e. `findViewById(R.id.productnameedittext)` is returning `null`... make sure that an `EditText` with ID `R.id.productnameedittext` is a part of your `Activity` layout...

Comment: @ Gopal Rao. but why?? Is the edittext which is in the xml of the dialog is not accessible here. I have entered a value inside the edittext and when i press ok of dialog, then it force closes. How to get the entered value in the edittext of the xml file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47628/discussion-between-gopal-rao-and-user1547124)